# Wordpress Infinite scroll never stops loading (doesn't force 404)

Tags: php, wordpress, doctype, infinite-scroll

Okay, so I've gotten the infinite scroll plugin for Wordpress to work almost perfectly. The exception is that when the plugin tries to load a page that doesn't have any more posts (e.g. my-site/page/4/) it appends the posts from the initial page instead of returning a 404 page and thus kill infinite scroll. This results in the plugin never stopping loading posts.

I found the `paged_404_fix()` in the php file and changed it like this:

```
function paged_404_fix( ) {
  global $wp_query; 

  // I Have no idea why this worked, but it did, but for some reason it removed 
  // the strict doctype from the html and made the plugin act weird.
  echo count($wp_query->posts);

  if ( is_404() || !is_paged() || 0 != count( $wp_query->posts ) ){
      return;
  }

  $wp_query->set_404();
  status_header( 404 );
  nocache_headers();
}
```

The page that contains my posts is the "Posts page" pointing to a custom page.

I dont know if this is of any use but if I go to my-site/page/4 in the address bar I get redirected to my-site/ but if i go to my-site/page/random-string I get a 404.

Im suspecting that `paged_404_fix()` is fetching posts from the start page because my-site/page/4/ redirects to the start page.

Anyone had a similar problem with this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it had to do with the "Wordpress SEO by Yoast" plugins new update:

> -Redirect paginated archive pages with a pagination number that doesn't exist to the first page of that archive.

This was the reason infinite scroll never stopped loading posts.

For more info: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/enhancement-in-update-messes-up-infinite-scroll-plugin